# Is it possible to hide the axis of a flex chart and have it not take up any space?

Tags: apache-flex, charts

Is it possible to tell flex to display a chart with no visible axis?  I want the contents of the chart to take up all the available space.  I can set the visibility on the AxisRenderer to false which will hide the axis but that leaves an empty space where the axis would usually be.  How can I remove this empty space?

```
   <mx:horizontalAxis>
      <mx:DateTimeAxis id="xAxis" dataUnits="hours" />
   </mx:horizontalAxis>
   <mx:horizontalAxisRenderers>
      <mx:AxisRenderer axis="{xAxis}" visible="false" height="0" />
   </mx:horizontalAxisRenderers>
```

I've tried setting the height on the renderer but that has no effect, and there is no height style on the axis itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This goes for all flex components - `visible='false'` makes them disappear from the view. But they are actually still there, not being drawn, but taking place. There's a second parameter called `includeInLayout` which, when set to false, makes them stop taking place.

Comment: This is true for most UIComponents, but in this case it doesn't seem to work - the white space is still there.  I found that Clement's solution worked.

Answer (score 9):

You need to set the size of each elements in the AxisRenderer to 0.
Try this in reference to the documentation : [Setting padding properties](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=charts_formatting_05.html)

```
   <mx:horizontalAxisRenderers>
      <mx:AxisRenderer axis="{xAxis}" 
                       minorTickPlacement="none" 
                       tickPlacement="none" 
                       labelGap="0" 
                       showLabels="false" 
                       showLine="false" />
   </mx:horizontalAxisRenderers>
```

There still one pixel on borders but you can set padding to -1 as trick, currently i don't find something better.

```
<mx:BarChart dataProvider="{data}"
             paddingBottom="-1" 
             paddingLeft="-1"
             paddingRight="-1"
             paddingTop="-1">
```