# Remove Flex Chart AxisRenderer in Layout?

Tags: apache-flex

I'm trying to hide both the vertical and horizontal axis renderers in flex so I can take a picture of the chart without them.

I've set both renders to visible = false and includeInLayout = false.  They don't show up but they still take space.  I've tried setting widths/heights to 0 and that doesn't help either.

```
        <mx:horizontalAxisRenderers>
        <mx:AxisRenderer
            id="horizontalAxisRenderer"
            axis="{dtAxis}"
            axisStroke="{axis}" 
            placement="bottom"
            minorTickPlacement="outside" 
            minorTickLength="10" 
            tickLength="12" 
            tickPlacement="outside"
            color="0x707275"
            styleName="axisStyle"
            visible="false"
            includeInLayout="false"
            >
            <mx:tickStroke>{ticks}</mx:tickStroke>
            <mx:minorTickStroke>{mticks}</mx:minorTickStroke>
        </mx:AxisRenderer>
    </mx:horizontalAxisRenderers>

    <mx:verticalAxisRenderers>
        <mx:AxisRenderer
            id="verticalAxisRenderer"
            axis="{laMain}"
            axisStroke="{axis}" 
            placement="bottom"
            minorTickPlacement="outside" 
            minorTickLength="10" 
            tickLength="12" 
            tickPlacement="outside"
            fontSize="15"
            color="0x707275"
            labelGap="0"
            styleName="axisStyle"
            visible="false"
            includeInLayout="false"
            >
            <mx:tickStroke>{ticks}</mx:tickStroke>
            <mx:minorTickStroke>{mticks}</mx:minorTickStroke>
        </mx:AxisRenderer>
    </mx:verticalAxisRenderers>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A similar question [was asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161596/is-it-possible-to-hide-the-axis-of-a-flex-chart-and-have-it-not-take-up-any-space), and by building upon [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161596/is-it-possible-to-hide-the-axis-of-a-flex-chart-and-have-it-not-take-up-any-space/2318960#2318960) I was able to find success.  Try something like the following, adjusting your axis type if needed from LinearAxis to whatever you might be using:

```
  <mx:horizontalAxis>
    <mx:LinearAxis id="myXAxis" />
  </mx:horizontalAxis>
  <mx:horizontalAxisRenderers>
    <mx:AxisRenderer axis="{myXAxis}"
                     minorTickPlacement="none"
                     tickPlacement="none"
                     labelGap="0"
                     showLabels="false" showLine="false"
                     visible="false" includeInLayout="false" />
  </mx:horizontalAxisRenderers>
```

I still needed to keep the binding between the renderer and the axis.  Without it, the app didn't seem to want to load at all.

Comment: Hey, that was it!  I guess even though you tell it not to include in layout it's still reading a bunch of other values.  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove/hide the axis, why do you have all that binded info going in?

```
<mx:AxisRenderer visible="false" includeInLayout="false" />
```

Should do it.

Comment: That's the same as the code I posted.  It is still included in the layout.

Comment: No, it isn't the same code.  You have a lot extra properties being added.  Try this alone to see if it works.

Comment: It doesn't work for me, the renderer requires an axis object: "Error: Property axis is not set for this AxisRenderer".

Comment: I have this same issue - i just can't remove default VerticalAxisRenderer from view.
I have many dynamic (as3) axisRenderer hidden, but this one is still visible - i have no idea how to make it work. Do you have solution?

Answer (score 1):

To add axis renderer dynamically, you should do this.

```
var tp:Array = barChart.verticalAxisRenderers;
axisRenderer = new AxisRenderer();
axisRenderer.axis = v2Axis;
axisRenderer.placement = "right";
tp.push(axisRenderer);
barChart.verticalAxisRenderers = tp;
```

here v2Axis is the verticalAxis for which we are adding this renderer. The chart already has vertical Axis on the left hand side. We have just added one more vertical axis to the right hand side.

If you want to hide the axis renderer do this

```
var tp:Array = barChart.verticalAxisRenderers;
axisRenderer.includeInLayout =false;
axisRenderer.visible = false;
tp = null;
barChart.verticalAxisRenderers = tp;
```

Here barChart is the id of the chart. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the left, right, top, bottom gutters to a small value. These determine the dimentions of the gap into with AxisRenderes are placed. The chart computes these automatically by default. It may be the case that it is not taking into account the visible and includeInLayout properties while computing the gutters. See [computedGutters and dataRegion](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/charts/chartClasses/CartesianChart.html#computedGutters) for more details on the working of these.